# cant start SonarQube docker container via Marathon with port mapping

Tags: docker, sonarqube, marathon, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to run sonarqube docker container with port mapping to expose ui on 9050 instead of default 9000. This command  works well:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9050:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

But via Marathon the following error occured:

> 2016.05.23 12:12:40 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of
>   the configured nodes are available: []    at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
>   ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]

```
 {
     "id": "/sonarqube",
     "cmd": null,
     "cpus": 1,
     "mem": 500,
     "disk": 800,
     "instances": 0,
     "container": {
         "type": "DOCKER",
         "volumes": [],
         "docker": {
             "image": "sonarqube",
             "network": "BRIDGE",
             "portMappings": [
             {
                 "containerPort": 9000,
                 "hostPort": 9050,
                 "servicePort": 10105,
                 "protocol": "tcp",
                 "labels": {}
             },
             {
                 "containerPort": 9092,
                 "hostPort": 9092,
                 "servicePort": 10106,
                 "protocol": "tcp",
                 "labels": {}
             },
             {
                 "containerPort": 9001,
                 "hostPort": 9051,
                 "servicePort": 10107,
                 "protocol": "tcp",
                 "labels": {}
             }
             ],
             "privileged": false,
             "parameters": [],
             "forcePullImage": false
         }
    },
    "portDefinitions": [
      {
        "port": 10105,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "labels": {}
      },
      {
        "port": 10106,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "labels": {}
      },
      {
        "port": 10107,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "labels": {}
      }
    ]
}
```

[the log file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s-bjm8XE1j2CQszX8PHdsMQsrIrjYl9_2Y1XG-Uvv-U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

i gues you have to fill cmd and it should look like "cmd": "./bin/run.sh".
tell me if that